# .NET Process Monitor

Tags: c#, process, system

Is there a way to determine when the last time a specific machine last ran a process?

I can use the following to determine if a process is running, but the application cannot grab the process if it has since stopped.

```
Process[] process = Process.GetProcessesByName(processName, serverName);
```

Answer (score 76, accepted):

WMI provides a way to track processes starting and terminating with the Win32_ProcessTrace classes.  Best shown with an example.  Start a new Console application, Project + Add Reference, select System.Management.  Paste this code:

```
using System;
using System.Management;

class Process {
  public static void Main() {
    ManagementEventWatcher startWatch = new ManagementEventWatcher(
      new WqlEventQuery("SELECT * FROM Win32_ProcessStartTrace"));
    startWatch.EventArrived += new EventArrivedEventHandler(startWatch_EventArrived);
    startWatch.Start();
    ManagementEventWatcher stopWatch = new ManagementEventWatcher(
      new WqlEventQuery("SELECT * FROM Win32_ProcessStopTrace"));
    stopWatch.EventArrived += new EventArrivedEventHandler(stopWatch_EventArrived);
    stopWatch.Start();
    Console.WriteLine("Press any key to exit");
    while (!Console.KeyAvailable) System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(50);
    startWatch.Stop();
    stopWatch.Stop();
  }

  static void stopWatch_EventArrived(object sender, EventArrivedEventArgs e) {
    Console.WriteLine("Process stopped: {0}", e.NewEvent.Properties["ProcessName"].Value);
  }

  static void startWatch_EventArrived(object sender, EventArrivedEventArgs e) {
    Console.WriteLine("Process started: {0}", e.NewEvent.Properties["ProcessName"].Value);
  }
}
```

[Edit the manifest](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2818776/17034) so this program runs elevated.  Then simply start some programs to see it at work.  Beware that it is not especially quick.

Comment: It works perfectly, but the delay is annoying, is there anyway to get it faster?

Comment: I just tried it and have a delay of less then 1 second. I think this is ok.

Comment: It's great, I want to wait until a command-line application process was initialized but I'm relutanct to request to the user to the application to run as adm

Answer (score 6):

You won't be able to do this using the `Process` class. However, it should be possible to figure out when an application was last run by configuring audit process tracking in Windows. The following links might get you started:

> [Audit process tracking](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc775520%28WS.10%29.aspx)
>
> [How can I track what programs come and go on my machine?](http://ask-leo.com/how_can_i_track_what_programs_come_and_go_on_my_machine.html)

The process tracking will create entries in the Windows event log which you can then access using C#.