# Is there a windows message that I can hook for when an application starts?

Tags: hook, windows-messages

I want to know whenever any application starts. Is there a windows message that I can set a hook for to know exactly when that happens?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If polling is not a problem you could use one of the approaches described in the answers to a related question:

> [C# Process Monitor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1986249/c-process-monitor)

The suggested solutions use WMI or Windows audit process tracking mechanism.

Comment: Wow, I think that can work really well for what I am trying to do. Great suggestion!

Answer (score 1):

The first message sent to new windows is `WM_NCCREATE`. But this has nothing to do with the *process* itself, which is what I suspect you're asking? By definition 'window messages' will start to arrive only after you create a window (using `CreateWindowEx` or whatever), but that can happen long after the process has started.

You don't say what language/framework you're using. In VC++ and the like you can just use whatever passes for the WinMain function. For VB it would be a `Main` function in a module.

Comment: Thank you for yoru response. If I used WM_NCCREATE, would I be able to know which process was started? It sounds like I wouldn't, from your comment. I'll be using C++ for the hook. What difference would that make?