# what can you query using the ManagementEventWatcher class

Tags: c#, managementeventwatcher

have been playing with the ManagementEventWatcher class and am curious what system events and objects you can select * *from* ..

Is there a published list somewhere?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You'll want to download and experiment with the [WMI Code Creator](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyID=2cc30a64-ea15-4661-8da4-55bbc145c30e&displaylang=en) utility.  The available events are listed under the "Receive an event" tab.

An example in C# is available in [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1986249/c-process-monitor/1986856).

Formal documentation for the WMI classes and their events [starts here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa394554%28VS.85%29.aspx).