# Detecting child processes

Tags: c++, windows

Is there a way (in C++ & windows XP) to detect if one process spawns any other processes?

for example,

write.exe in system32 spawns wordpad.exe then disappears, is there a function that tells me if the process is about to do this?

for those interested i solved the problem using this section of msdn:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa390425(v=VS.85).aspx

Comment: The answer will be Windows-specific and somewhat irrelevant to C++ in particular since C++ itself knows nothing of such concepts.  But I'm curious about the answer.

Comment: @John Dibling: Do you mean OS-specific? I'm fairly sure you can determine 'parent process' under Linux.

Comment: i know that you can detect parents of a process, but that's not my question. i would like to know if it's possible to detect when a process spawns another one

Comment: Even Windows specific is a bit broad because it will require drivers so it will vary between Windows 'flavors'. For a rather old example of how it can be done on XP (and should work on older NTs) see here: http://www.codeproject.com/KB/system/soviet_protector.aspx

Comment: AFAIK no direct API for that, but you can always watch the processes (polling). Checking for process parent is a bit undocumented and it's also unreliable. Why do you want to do this?

Comment: @alf: updated with an example
@eugen: thanks, i will have a read of that when i get back from work

Comment: @sje397: Tom tagged the question "windows" so I drilled down.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Nothing in the Win32 API for this.  However, it is supported through WMI with the Win32_ProcessStartTrace query.  You'll find some C# code that demonstrates the query in my answer in [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1986249/c-process-monitor/1986856#1986856).  Writing WMI code in C++ is fairly painful, you'll find a link to boilerplate code you have to write in the MSDN Library article.

Do beware that this isn't particularly fast.  It isn't clear to me how much help the WMI provider gets from the kernel to generate the notification but given the speed it quacks like polling.  In other words, the process is likely to be well on its way by the time you get the notification.  This is otherwise par for the course on a multitasking operating system.

Comment: thanks, found this section of msdn that answered my question :)

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa390425(v=VS.85).aspx

Comment: @Tom, I tried the sample, it does do the event notification but it's through a COM interface. Do you have example how you got it to work?

Answer (score 3):

You can enumerate over the process tree, which identifies running processes and their parents. This is the inverse of what you want (you want to identify child processes, not parent processes). But of course by keeping track of parent process IDs while enumerating, you can identify which sub-processes a given process has spawned.

To do this, call [`CreateToolhelp32Snapshot`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms682489.aspx) and then use [`Process32First`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms684834.aspx) and [`Process32Next`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms684836.aspx) to enumerate the processes. The enumeration will fill in a [`PROCESSENTRY32`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms684839.aspx) struct that contains a `th32ParentProcessID` member.

This is a polling method; there may be another way of actually hooking the `CreateProcess` function, but I don’t have any information about that.

Comment: hi, yes i have that functionality already in the program, but your method would mean iterating over the process tree even when there might not have been child processes spawned. i would rather it was an events based solution i.e something is emitted when one process calls createprocess (or similar functions)

Answer (score 0):

I think you would need to make a global hook DLL that attaches itself to every running process. DLL then finds a place where a function call to CreateProcess is mapped to actual CreateProcess from kernel32, and change a table entry to redirect the call to it's own code to "detect" the call to CreateProcess. All this assuming that some user firewall will not prevent your global hook from executing.