# how do i make a wrapper process to monitor some processes

Tags: c++, operating-system, wrapper

i want to monitor some processes with a wrapper process which can intercept all messages, function calls, library usages, and hw driver usages(everything!!) from the target process.

the purpose is to analyze how the process controls some machines(in the view of machine controls).

i had some researches but have no clue.
what should i know for this?

languages will be no matter and i consider win32/nt environment.

and i have some cs background but dont have low level hw control things or machine controls

Comment: There will be many ways to do it... Let us know what you are comfortable with so that u can be directed properly...

Comment: i prefer c++ and it will be good if the way can be applied without rebooting pc.

Comment: i am considering making a independent program which is executed at the same time and monitor/intercept the target program/process

Comment: Ok... Can you take a look at [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8540299/c-monitor-running-processes-in-the-background), hope it helps you start...