# How to catch Windows os events? (C#)

Tags: c#, windows, events

I want to loging all programs and files what user had opened, to create own frequently used programs list in Windows using C# programming language. Thanks for helping.

Comment: You can track all processes that are started, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1986249/c-process-monitor

Comment: @Adrian Faciu, that solution will have performance implications

Comment: @HABJAN: Perhaps, but not nearly as bad performance as the polling method you suggested.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no easy way to accomplish this. Windows does not provide such events.

What you can do is:

1. Each couple of seconds loop thru all opened windows or running processes and get their informations. For windows enumeration you can use logic from: http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cs/WindowTabifier.aspx
2. You can use methods like injecting dll into the taskmanager, hooking the TerminateProcess in Kernel32.. etc.. Related sample: http://www.codeproject.com/KB/threads/taskex.aspx,

Answer (score 0):

```
Process[] processlist = Process.GetProcesses();

foreach(Process theprocess in processlist){
Console.WriteLine(“Process: {0} ID: {1}”, theprocess.ProcessName, theprocess.Id);
}
```

This will give you the details of the process that is currently running, can't you periodically review this list to find new applicatons launched.