# C# Raise an event when a new process starts

Tags: c#

Hey there, Is there a way to raise event when a new process is started without using the ManagementEventWatcher, and without using the Process.GetProcesses()?
The problem with ManagementEventWatcher is that the user needs to have high premmisions.
Thank you!!!

Comment: Instead of attempting to circumvent the security model, how about telling us what problem you are actually trying to solve?  There may be a better overall approach that you haven't thought of.

Comment: I'm creating a game (Treasure Hunt) that use windows for the playground so, when I open a new notepad or calc I will send hints to the process.. so I need to raise event when the next process starts so i can send the hints for the  treasure.... i hope you get it....

Comment: Have you tried `ManagementEventWatcher`?  I don't see anything in the docs that says it needs high permissions, although I'll admit that I haven't tried it on a very restricted user account.

Comment: Yes I tryed that: startWatch = new ManagementEventWatcher(new WqlEventQuery("SELECT * FROM Win32_ProcessStartTrace"));
                startWatch.EventArrived += new EventArrivedEventHandler(startWatch_EventArrived);
                startWatch.Start();  after the startWatch.Start(); line the exception is thrown[Access is denied], but when I open as administrator everything is fine

Comment: Does the game start the processes itself?

Comment: How much granularity do you need?  That is, how soon after the process begins do you need the event to be raised?

Comment: What a terrible playground for a game world, good luck trying to make it work! :)

Comment: Thank you for the responses but looks like the original asker of this question is not active anymore. I have awarded my bounty to Jeremy's answer below.

Answer (score 10):

Unlike the extrinsic event `Win32_ProcessStartTrace` that you are currently using, the `__InstanceCreationEvent` and `__InstanceDeletionEvent` WMI intrinsic events do not require administrator rights.

Here's a sample query you can use to track process starts:

```
SELECT TargetInstance 
  FROM __InstanceCreationEvent WITHIN 1 
 WHERE TargetInstance ISA 'Win32_Process' 
   AND TargetInstance.Name LIKE '<your process name.exe>'
```

Further info: [Process Information and Notifications using WMI](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/12138/Process-Information-and-Notifications-using-WMI)

Because these are intrinsic events, WMI ultimately mimics event behaviour by means of polling, and will check for new events only periodically (here, every 1 second). Decreasing the `WITHIN` duration to fractions of seconds will give you faster response at the expense of CPU usage.

Comment: You should note that a very short polling interval (e.g. 0.1s) can eat up up to 30% of CPU not in your process but WmiPrvSE.exe which does the actual polling. Just in case if you wonder why not your process is taking suddenly so much CPU but one system process.

Answer (score 0):

Strange thing is an application does not need to create a window in windows. Create process may not belong to the window-station that you work on. You will need to find windows of that process anyway, and you will also need to detect new and closed windows of all processes.

So enumerating windows is much cleaner/easier choice.

Try `EnumChildWindows` function on desktop handle (retrieved by `GetDesktopWindow`) to find top level windows of applications. use `GetWindowThreadProcessId` and `EnumThreadWindows` on obtained handles to detect sub windows of windows.

A low priority thread will do the job.

Answer (score 0):

It should be possible to figure out when an application was last run by configuring audit process tracking in Windows. The following links might get you started:

> [Audit process tracking](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc775520%28WS.10%29.aspx)
>
> [How can I track what programs come and go on my machine?](http://ask-leo.com/how_can_i_track_what_programs_come_and_go_on_my_machine.html)

The process tracking will create entries in the Windows event log which you can then access using C#.

Ref: [.NET Process Monitor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1986249/c-sharp-process-monitor#answer-1986294)

Comment: This makes sense, and I can then subscribe to the event log updates without having to poll... http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb671202(v=vs.90).aspx. I think I will award the bounty to you.

Comment: Please note though that the original question was by a different asker, so I cannot mark your answer as accepted.

Comment: Isn't this a verbatim copy of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1986249/c-sharp-process-monitor#answer-1986294? Is it normal to get a bounty for that? Shouldn't the bounty belong to [0xA3](http://stackoverflow.com/users/40347/0xa3)??

Comment: @7heo.tk this was ages ago, I have added ref to source, unfortunately you cant close active bounties as duplicates.

Answer (score 0):

You can probably use EnumDesktopWindows from user32.dll, you will get all the window handles, you can check the title of the window using GetWindowText, and type of window using GetClassName.

That way you can hide the hint or treasure anywhere. (because you will get handles of all the windows (and controls)).

See if this class will be useful to you 
[Managed Global Hook for Window Creation and Destruction](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/38523/How-to-Write-a-Managed-Global-Hook-for-Window-Crea)

On that article, someone has created nice class with easy to attach events, You can run that code without elevating privileges.

Once you get the window (control) handle, you can add text or draw image on it for hints.