# OS Process manager Listener in c#

Tags: c#

Is there any operating system's Process Manager library in c#? Forexample when new application started or closed I want to get that process name from my code.

Comment: Check the [`Process`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.process.aspx) class. One example: http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cs/CustomTaskManager.aspx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can try using this Namespace [System.Diagnostics](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.aspx)

```
foreach (System.Diagnostics.Process p in
    System.Diagnostics.Process.GetProcesses())
{
    // do ur stuff;

}
```

Comment: I know that I m asking Listener Library!

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1986249/c-sharp-process-monitor check this one