# Monitoring Unmanaged program using .net

Tags: c#, c++, .net, events, exe

I have a exe program written using `c++`,
I want to perform some actions when that `exe` is `opened, closed or minimized`
I wonder whether this kind of functionality is possible using `c#.net`?

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms747327%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Native .NET `Process` class has a functionality for an [event fired when a process is closed](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.process.exited%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

Also process monitoring in C# is partially discussed [in this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1986249/net-process-monitor#answer-1986294).

Considering this, you'll have to use [Windows Management Instrumentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa394582%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) to track wide range of specific process events.

Answer (score 1):

you can send windows message.
you also control on the window by using pipe name

```
A simple message pump looks like this:
[Serializable, StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
public struct MSG
{
    public IntPtr hwnd;
    public int message;
    public IntPtr wParam;
    public IntPtr lParam;
    public int time;
    public int pt_x;
    public int pt_y;
}

[DllImport("user32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Ansi)]
public static extern bool GetMessage([In, Out] ref MSG msg, IntPtr hWnd, int MsgFilterMin,  int uMsgFilterMax);

[DllImport("user32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto)]
public static extern IntPtr DispatchMessage([In] ref MSG msg);


[DllImport("user32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Unicode, SetLastError = true)]
public static extern uint RegisterWindowMessage(string lpString);

[DllImport("user32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
public static extern IntPtr SendMessage(IntPtr hWnd, uint Msg, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam);


    // #1
    MSG msg = new MSG();
    while (GetMessage(ref msg, IntPtr.Zero, 0, 0))
    {
        DispatchMessage(ref msg);
    }

    // #2
    uint UWM_UART_CTRL_TRS = Win32Api.RegisterWindowMessage("BT_UARTCTRL_TRANSFER");
    Win32Api.SendMessage(HWND_BROADCAST, UWM_UART_CTRL_TRS, (IntPtr)0, (IntPtr)0);

    // #3
    uint UWM_UART_CTRL_TRS = Win32Api.RegisterWindowMessage("BT_UARTCTRL_TRANSFER");
    Win32Api.SendMessage(HWND_BROADCAST, UWM_UART_CTRL_TRS, (IntPtr)1, (IntPtr)0);
```