# How to Detect If Target Process Has Ended?

Tags: vb.net

I want to detect if a target process has ended or not. I have written the expected sequence below:

1. A process named TEST runs at the background.
2. `Status.Text = "Running"` to indicate process is running.
3. Process ends by itself.
4. `Status.Text = "Finished"` right after the process ends.

Comment: What is the quesiton?

Comment: This may be of help: http://stackoverflow.com/a/1986856/1689180

Comment: Are you using vb.net or vb6 or VBA or the old BASIC ?

Comment: If you're creating the process in that application using Process.Start(), consider using [Process.WaitforExit()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fb4aw7b8%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

<sup>Unfortunately, the solution posted [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1986856/1689180) requires to be run as administrator.</sup>

A simple polling-solution using a timer *could* do the work just fine.
If you use a polling solution, then of course you have to re-read the processes inside the loop or polling event.
Use the process name without `.exe` here.

```
Private timer_watcher As Timer

Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Me.Label1.Text = "Watching"
    Me.timer_watcher = New Timer
    AddHandler timer_watcher.Tick, AddressOf TimerEvent
    timer_watcher.Interval = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1).TotalMilliseconds
    timer_watcher.Start()
End Sub

Public Sub TimerEvent(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)
    Dim p() As Process = System.Diagnostics.Process.GetProcessesByName("processname")
    If p.Length = 0 Then
        timer_watcher.Stop()
        Me.Label1.Text = "Stopped"
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks! Your solution worked but "Me.timer_watcher = New Timer" needs to be removed, generates overload errors. Thanks!

Comment: Well just to explain: The code works without using a Timer in the Designer. If you add it in the Designer, you can also set Interval and the Tick Method there.

Answer (score 0):

Consider using the [Process.Exited](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.process.exited(v=vs.110).aspx) event.

Comment: Dim p As Process = New Process()
I did this way, i can do p.HasExited

Comment: @BerkayOzturk So... what's the problem? Check my comment above.

Comment: @SomeNickName I want to display a message right after proccess exits, but dont know how to properly and continuously check if exited

Comment: @BerkayOzturk Did you check my comment above? Process.WaitForExit() should do it?

Comment: @SomeNickName I searched Process.WaitForExit() but dont really understand how to use it. Can you give me a quick example?

Comment: @BerkayOzturk the remarks section on the [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fb4aw7b8%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) explains it quite good, but i'll short: It stops the current thread until the process exits, after the process exits it continues the thread execution. Meaning you can call it when you want to do something after the process exits, if you don't want to block the thread, you can use the Exited event as @ Zev Spitz suggested.