# C# Detect if other programs are Opened and Closed (like an antivirus)

Tags: c#, process, monitoring, system.diagnostics

I'm new to Stack Overflow.

I'd thought I'd start with a puzzling question.
How can I monitor the system and detect when new processes are created and when they are closed.

I wouldn't have the slightest idea on how to do this other that a constantly refreshing listbox polling System.Diagnostics.Process.GetProcesses() every second.

I need a monitor that fires an event when a new process is added and a seperate event that fires when a process is closed.

I'm not looking for a process monitor that runs on a loop or a timer. I need a direct interface to the process list, so this thread [.NET Process Monitor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1986249/net-process-monitor)
Does not answer my question.
Ideas?

-- Caustic

Comment: Expanding on this, If I had some kind of class that for example when a program is opened or a new process is started it fires NewProcessCreated(processID,processName,processPublisher);

Comment: my approach doesn't use timer, it is based on events. this is what you want

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would use [TraceEvent](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Diagnostics.Tracing.TraceEvent), to start a [Realtime Session](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/vancem/2013/03/09/using-traceevent-to-mine-information-in-os-registered-etw-providers/) and activate provider `Microsoft-Windows-Kernel-Process`

[image]

In the code you can see the `ProcessStart` and `ProcessStop` handling and here you can add your own code to handle when you get this data.

Answer (score 0):

you can use Process.GetProcessesByName Method (String)  to  find whether a particular process is running or not.

```
 System.Diagnostics.Process[] proc = System.Diagnostics.Process.GetProcessesByName(sProcessName);
  if (proc.Length > 0)
  {
      MessageBox.Show(String.Format("{0}is  running!", sProcessName), sProcessName);
  }
  else
  {
      MessageBox.Show(String.Format("{0}is not running!", sProcessName), sProcessName);

   }
```

Comment: I'm not sure that is quite what OP asked. OP would like to constantly monitor processes rather than just check on occasion if one is there

Comment: He can use timer event or stopwatch class event to continuously monitor