# Monitor new processes as a non-admin

Tags: c#, process, system

There is a very [clear answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1986249/net-process-monitor) on how to monitor processes. It works like a charm... except it must be run in elevated mode, which is a definite non-option for me in the context of my program.

What I need to do is basically monitor all new processes and compare them against a predetermined list. I would like to do this without simply using a stopwatch and polling for any new processes.

Does anyone know of an event that would be raised similar to the `ManagementEventWatcher` that doesn't require to be run as administrator?

Thanks!

Comment: that'd be rather privileged information, and I highly doubt it'd be available to any standard user. "oh, look, user X is executing `chrome.exe http://furnitureporn.com`. oh MY...."

Comment: This would only be for processes run by that particular user. Non-admins have access to the entire `Process` class, but for that you have to supply the name of the process to monitor in advance. I want to have a general event for all processes, then check the name after the fact.

Comment: @MarcB I'm at work so I won't but now I'm extremely curious if that is a working url...

Comment: it is, and it's hilariously semi-safe for work. it's literally pictures of various furniture in sex positions. the site's been around since the VERY early days of the web.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem as OP but managed to use ManagementEventWatcher as non-admin by providing a specific query:

```cs
string queryString = "SELECT * FROM __InstanceCreationEvent WITHIN .025 WHERE TargetInstance ISA 'Win32_Process'";
ManagementEventWatcher managementEventWatcher = new ManagementEventWatcher(@"\\.\root\CIMV2", queryString);
managementEventWatcher.EventArrived += ProcessStartEventArrived;
managementEventWatcher.Start();
```

`WITHIN` is the timeframe to be notified in.

Stopping is done the same way but using `__InstanceDeletionEvent`

```cs
string queryString = "SELECT * FROM __InstanceDeletionEvent WITHIN .025 WHERE TargetInstance ISA 'Win32_Process'";
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get all working processes with `Process.GetProcesses();`, then you can iterate thought them and get their name and some info, but more advanced things do require elevated permissions.

Comment: I was hoping to avoid polling. I'd rather have a raised event if possible.