# Find javaw application details

Tags: java, c#, windows

To start, I will be using C#

I have managed to find a problem I can't quite get my head around. Some assistance is required.

So...When I launch some java applications, they give me a 'java.exe' instance, cool. Some applications also give me a 'javaw.exe' application.

How would I go about programmatically find out more information about this application. For example, when viewing the properties in the windows task manager I am able to see where the application launched from.

Is there any way I can get this information in c#?

Also, what should I do if there are multiple javaw instances and I am looking for a particular instance? Should I just iterate through each application or would there be a more efficient way of doing this?

Comment: perhaps try to look here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1986249/net-process-monitor

Comment: Are you asking how to use System.Diagnostics.Process.GetProcesses()?